# How to get the datatype of a kendo grid column using javascript?

Tags: javascript, types, kendo-ui

How do I get the datatype of a column in Kendo Grid on the client side in Javascript/Jquery? For eg I want to know whether the column is of type text or numeric or date. I checked inside
`$('#kendoGrid').data('kendoGrid').columns`, but it does not show any detail about the column data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema (if it was specified) is in the grid's data source. You will find it under `$('#kendoGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.options.schema.model.fields`. This returns an array of fields that should match up to the columns in your grid. Each field has a `type` property. Bear in mind that Kendo UI did not intend for the schema to be accessed in this way. I'm curious to know why you need this?

Comment: Im having a global filter on top of the grid that works in conjunction with the column filters. So when i enter something in the global filter i make it part of all the column filters with an OR logical operation so that it can search in all of the columns the value entered. The problem is if the data types are different then searching for a string when its expecting a date causes an error on the server side during retrieval. I use it this way because we have a lot of grids & we need some common way to do it. If there is a better approach im open to it. Thanks in advance

Comment: For generic code for a work-around for the date problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011886/custom-filter-in-kendo-grid-passing-null-values-when-usign-serevr-side-filtering